# QML: C++ classes with "bring your own component"

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I'm trying to develop a Qt C++ application, with a QML frontend, but I hit a roadblock.

This is what I have so far:

- A Factory class that outputs a choice of objects. These objects, that I'm going to call "controllers", control different pieces of hardware.

  - The Factory would be exposed to the QML layer with `setContextProperty`.
  - The controller would be chosen basically with a combo box controlling the factory.

Now, for the tricky bit. I want that the "controllers" behave in a "bring your own component" way. This means that they would have a method returning the respective QML file for their controller. That shouldn't be to hard to do, it's basically biding a `Loader` to a method of the Factory/Manager saying the file with the component to load into a placeholder.

But the problem is: how can this newly created component and this newly created controller know and talk to each other? This is something I did before with QWidgets, just having pointers between the classes. Quite trivial.

I tried an architecture like this before for QWidgets, but seems to not be ideal for QML.

I made this drawing of what I would ultimately like to happen:
[image: ArchIdea]

This architecture allows for a very trivial plugin system (at least in the QWidgets world) and I would very much like to keep that. Not a massive singleton and account for every possible action...

I'd appreciate ideas!

Comment: What is exactly your problem? You need to pass to Loader a special data (pointer to controler to specific hw controler) along with the file name?

Comment: I guess that's more or less it, yes. When the component is created I need a way to tell it what the c++ object is.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is actually very easy, if you return a QQuickItem from the C++ side. If you do so you can create it with a specific context, in which you can set your "specific hardware controller" as a property

```
QQmlComponent *qml_controller = new QQmlComponent(qengine, "some_file.qml");
QQmlContext *context = new QQmlContext(); //should probably give a pointer to owning object
context->setContextProperty("controller", pointer_to_hw_cont);

return qml_controller->create(context);
```

Comment: Isn't manipulating the UI from the C++ side an anti-pattern with QML?

Comment: @RuiOliveira good question, obviously a bit subjective. But in this case I wouldn't say so, this is not that much more than a Loader like Arpegius' answer (but a bit more managed). (I get that anti-pattern feeling more when people want to find a object by id to set a property on it)

Answer (score 1):

The Loader `setSource` method have additional parameter you could pass to provide initial value for some property. Something like this:

```
ComboBox {
   model: controlerFactory.specificHWListModel
   onCurrentTextChanged: {
       var specificHWControler = controlerFactory.getObjectFor( currentText );
       loader1.setSource( 
           specificHWControler.qml_file,
           { "controler": specificHWControler }
       );
   }
}
Loader { 
    id: loader1
}
```

The `specificHWListModel` cold be QStringList or some custom QAbstractListModel.
And `getObjectFor`could be just a invokable function.

```
Q_INVOKABLE QObject* getObjectFor(QString hwName);
```

The object returned from `Q_INVOKABLE` function will be managed by `QQmlEngine` by default if you don't set by the `QQmlEngine::setObjectOwnership`. Remember to register your `SpecificHWControler` class to `QQmlEngine`.

The qml_file `SpecificView.ui.qml`, should have property controler, and could be edited with Designer:

```
import SpecificHWControlerModule 1.0
Item {
    property SpecificHWControler controler

}
```

https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/quick-connections-backend.html